# How to handle merges/conflicts in my git based wiki?

Tags: python, git, merge, conflict, resolve

I'm working on a django-based wiki. It has section edit capabilities (the sections being delimited by the markdown headers) and it is using git (a single repo) to store the revisions, via the Git Python library.

I'm trying to figure out how I can handle several concurrent edits of the same page (using git-python).

Thanks,

Comment: Try to merge and if it fails, show error to the user.

Comment: Jarrod, indeed I should... I'll try to fix that

Comment: svick, do you have any technical solution to that?

Answer (score 2):

Study how other systems (like e.g. ikiwiki) handle these things.

Commit requests will come in sequentially. Try to commit them. If there are conflicts or if a commit request is based on a previous HEAD, report that back to the person sending the commit request complete with the differences of the edits with the current HEAD.